# Regular expressions for numeric input

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression in which user could input only numeric or there be asterisk in the end. for example

12345,
123*,
5677*,
*

but I don't know how to do this. any help?

I have tried this regular expression for numeric input but I don't know that if I want asterisk(*) in the end than what should be the regular expression

```
^[0-9]+$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the input can be only `*` as well, so make the digit(`0-9`) portion optional and add additional `\*` at the end to accept asterisks.

```
^([0-9]+|[0-9]*\*)$
```

Comment: this is okay... but if user type (*) only then system is not accepting in your case.

Comment: @FahadMurtaza I have updated my answer. Kindly check.